# Efficeint way to differentiate arraylists of same type

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist

I have 20 arraylists (more to come) containing the same type of data:

1. var arraylist1 = ArrayList()
2. var arraylist2 = ArrayList()
3. var arraylist3 = ArrayList()

And so on.

All the arrays make up a list on different tabs in my app which the user clicks and I can differentiate where the clicks are coming from.

Now I need to clear all arrays except the one where the click came from.

Lets say that I write a function like this

```
clearAllArraysExceptThis(arraylist1)
```

Assuming that the click originated from `arraylist1`. How do I clear all the remaining lists efficiently.

Do I keep a list of the arraylists and get the name loop and compare or is there a better way ?

Comment: Perhaps you could consider storing the array lists in a HashMap and removing based on key

Comment: seems like the good option, why don't post it as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: How would a map help here @Feedbacker? Surely a list would make more sense?

Comment: You might be approaching this the wrong way. I would simply send the id of each tab (`0`, `1`, or `2`) and then have a `ArrayList<ArrayList<>>()` where I would look up the right `ArrayList` (or even better, since we're using Kotlin, `List`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With kotlin, assuming the following mock lists:

```
val list1 = arrayListOf(1, 2)
val list2 = arrayListOf(2, 2)
val list3 = arrayListOf(3, 2)

val lists = arrayListOf(list1, list2, list3)
```

To clear all the lists except the list function parameter, it would look something like this:

```
fun clearAllArraysExceptThis(listToKeep: List<Int>) {
    for (list in lists) {
        if (list != listToKeep) list.clear()
    }
}
```

A more functional approach would be:

```
fun clearAllArraysExceptThis(listToKeep: List<Int>) {
    lists.filter { list -> list != listToKeep }
            .forEach { list -> list.clear() }
}
```

If you want to actually *remove* the lists instead of clearing them, you could use:

```
fun clearAllArraysExceptThis(listToKeep: List<Int>) {
    lists.removeAll { it != listToKeep }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an arrayList of arrayLists called "AllArrayListTogether" where you add all yor arrayLists. Then create a function called "clearAllArraysExceptThis" whit one parameter "arrayListSelected".

Then do something like this:

```
public void clearAllArraysExceptThis(ArrayList arrayListSelected){
   for(ArrayList i : AllArrayListTogether){
      if(!i.equals(arrayListSelected){
          i.clear();
      }
   }
}
```